# Get infos about exchange mailbox

Tags: exchangewebservices, mapi

Is there a way to retrieve the max allowed size of email that can be send throught an EWS SOAP request or by a MAPI property tag?

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a **GetMailTips** operation that returns **MaxMessageSize** element

```
<t:MaxMessageSize xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">10485760</t:MaxMessageSize>
```

Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
        xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"> 
  <soap:Header> 
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010" /> 
  </soap:Header> 
  <soap:Body> 
    <GetMailTips xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"> 
      <SendingAs> 
        <t:EmailAddress> user1@contoso.com </t:EmailAddress> 
        <t:RoutingType>SMTP</t:RoutingType> 
      </SendingAs> 
      <Recipients> 
        <t:Mailbox> 
          <t:EmailAddress> user2@contoso.com </t:EmailAddress> 
          <t:RoutingType>SMTP</t:RoutingType> 
        </t:Mailbox> 
      </Recipients> 
      <MailTipsRequested>All</MailTipsRequested> 
    </GetMailTips> 
  </soap:Body> 
</soap:Envelope>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877060(v=exchg.150).aspx

Answer (score 1):

## It depends on your Exchange Version

From Microsofts [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2011/06/23/exchange-online-throttling-and-limits-faq/):

`maxReceivedMessageSize (WCF) – Identifies the maximum message size that is accepted by EWS. This maximum message size is 35,000,000 bytes, which translates to 25 MB of base64-encoded data.
Note: The values for this limit differ for an on-premise Exchange 2010 deployment. In the initial release version of Exchange 2010, the message size limit is 10 MB. In Exchange 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1), the message size limit is 35 MB.`

Comment: I wanted to get the message size limit througth an EWS SOAP request

Answer (score 1):

Read `PR_MAX_SUBMIT_MESSAGE_SIZE` property (`0x666D0003`) from the IMsgStore object.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, when I try to request this property through a SOAP request with a GetFolder operation it returns nothing
<t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyTag="0x666D" PropertyType="Integer"/>
I am querying the folder msgfolderroot
I tryed also with root

Comment: I have never tried this property with a SOAP call. It works fine in MAPI